# What should I do about an associative jquery array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, associative

I'm a new jquery learner. I have a question.

I wrote this script but the result it's not correct.

```
var details = <?php echo json_encode($all_data["holiday"]);?>;
var myArray = details.split("|");
var a = {};
var natDays = [];

for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    var ex_array = myArray[i].split(",");
    a["month"] = ex_array[0];
    a["date"] = ex_array[1];
    a["name"] = ex_array[2];

    natDays.push(a);
}

alert( JSON.stringify(natDays) );
```

I get the following incorrect result in alert:

```
[
    {"month":"3","date":"7","name":"test"},
    {"month":"3","date":"7","name":"test"},
    {"month":"3","date":"7","name":"test"},
    {"month":"3","date":"7","name":"test"}
]
```

It should be:

```
[
    {"month":"4","date":"11","name":"test"},
    {"month":"4","date":"4","name":"test"},
    {"month":"4","date":"13","name":"song kran festival"},
    {"month":"3","date":"7","name":"test"}
]
```

What should I do? Please advise.

Comment: Pls show what's `$all_data["holiday"]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you push a reference to the same object (stored in `a`) at each step of the loop - as by `a['month']` etc. you just augment an existing object, not create a new one.

To solve this, get rid off this `a` variable and create a new object at each step directly, with `object literal` notation:

```
for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++){
   var ex_array = myArray[i].split(",");
   natDays.push({
     month: ex_array[0],
     date: ex_array[1],
     name: ex_array[2]
   });
}
```

You can make this code even more concise by using [**jQuery.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var natDays = $.map(myArray, function(rec) {
  var fields = rec.split(',');
  return {
    month: fields[0],
    date: fields[1],
    name: fields[2]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create `a` INSIDE the loopp

```
....
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
   var a = {};
   ^^^^^^^^^^^ here
   var ex_array = myArray[i].split(",");
```